# Read Character string from H5 file using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I need to read string characters such as quality flag (good, bad, caution) from H5 data using matlab, similar way as the data read read in idl, however it doesn't work. I am using matlab2009a version.Please let me know whether I can read the character string of h5 files as 'byte array' and put numbers such as 0,1,2 for the character flags (good, caution, bad). 
I can able to read other parameters such as lat, lon, data (all numeric) except charcter string. Appreciate your help.

For an E.g'

```
FILE_NAME='acos_L2s_091101_17_Production_v050050_L 2s2800_r01_PolB_110305035627.h5'

file_id = H5F.open (FILE_NAME, 'H5F_ACC_RDONLY', 'H5P_DEFAULT');

Flag_NAME = 'RetrievalResults/master_quality_flag';

Flag_id = H5D.open (file_id, Flag_NAME);

flag=H5D.read (data_id,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT'); 
% (Doesn't work)

`enter code here`OR
flag=H5D.read (data_id,'H5T_C_S1', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT');
% (not working)
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you exactly want to do but it will probably be easier using a higher level HDF5 function like [hdf5read](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hdf5read.html):

```
flag = hdf5read(FILE_NAME, Flag_NAME);
```

Comment: I am using the matlab version 2009a, the syntax hdf5read is not working with the version. H5D.READ is working for reading lat, lon, data except the string character.

Comment: Based on above example, Please let me know how can I read the character string of h5 files as 'byte array' and put numbers such as 0,1,2 for the character flags (good, caution, bad).thanks in advance